# C++: Call a function from a user input

Tags: python, c++

In python, when i have several different functions that get called based on user input, I have a dictionary with the user input as a key and the function name as the value.

```
def x(y):
    return y

def z(y):
    return y

functions = {
    'x': x
    'z': z
}

print(functions[input()]())
```

Does anybody have any idea of how this can be done in c++?

Comment: In pretty much the same way, create a `std::map` with the function name as the key and a function pointer as the value.

Comment: You still can use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to store function pointers. But even better would be to store `std::function` in the map. By the way, what if the user input is not in `{'x', 'z'}`?

Comment: One more issue: each function in your snippet accepts an argument. The `functions[input()]()` doesn't provide any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something similar in C++ like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

void one() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, I'm one.\n";
}

void two() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, I'm two.\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functions = { 
        {"one", one}, 
        {"two", two} 
    };

    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    functions[s]();

    return 0;
}
```

Then, you shouldn't do it neither in Python, nor in C++ since:

1. you need to check that user input is fine
2. you need to pass parameters to your Python functions.

The main difference between the Python version and the C++ one is that Python functions could have different parameters and return values, and that even if they share the same structure, input and output types can be different. Function `x` in your question accepts anything. One could argue on the usefulness of that.

In any case you can do also that in C++, but it is way harder.

Comment: Yah I usually put the input inside a try-except block and have some sort of while loop. Thanks for the help!